# Rails - Access user_1 in a different model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm trying to access a Model that holds two users -> user_1_id and user_2_id. When calling current_user.modelname It thinks I'm trying to call user_id instead of user_1_id or user_2_id. Is there a way to specify user_1_id or user_2_id instead of user_id when calling that model?

Here's the code that throwing the error:

```
current_user.occupied_sessions.each
```

User model:

```
has_many :occupied_sessions , -> {where(trainer_sesses: {confirmation: "occupied"})}, through: :trainer_sesses, :source => :trainer
```

Error:

> PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column trainer_sesses.user_id does not exist at character 122 HINT: Perhaps you meant to reference the column "trainer_sesses.user_1_id" or the column "trainer_sesses.user_2_id". : SELECT "trainers".* FROM "trainers" INNER JOIN "trainer_sesses" ON "trainers"."id" = "trainer_sesses"."trainer_id" WHERE "trainer_sesses"."user_id" = $1 AND "trainer_sesses"."confirmation" = $2

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think by convention Rails assumes that the foreign key of User in TrainerSesses will be user_id. Therefore you will need to overwrite this behaviour. 
I'm unsure exactly what your database schema is so I've put has_many :trainer_sesses but you can change that to whatever your association is supposed to be!

Try something like this in your User model:

```
has_many :occupied_sessions,-> {where(trainer_sesses: {confirmation: "occupied"})}, through: :trainer_sesses, :source => :trainer,
has_many :trainer_sesses, :foreign_key => :user_1_id
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it!